# Visual Studio Memory Hog

Tags: visual-studio, memory, resources, windows-services

I have installed Visual Studio Express Web Developer 2010 and boy it really slows my system down a lot. Is there a way to identify the services like SQL Server and set them to manual so I can avoid all my memory resources been occupied when not using Visual Studio? Is it just SQL Express the problem or are there any other things I should consider disabling in order to have a fast and reliable system when not using Visual Studio?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you look with a program like [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) you'll see that the biggest one is the SQL server that boots with your system. I wouldn't really recommend disabling it if you use databases a lot because it can be quite the trouble getting it back to run.

I wouldn't suggest on disabling any startup program that you cannot see in the startup tab of 'msconfig'. They aren't there for a reason.

However I will agree with you that Visual Studio slows down your system, I too notice the same on my laptop. It just installs sooo many things.